# how to store the dictionary in genism which has been created for the specific dataset?

Tags: python, dictionary, lda, topic-modeling

How to store the dictionary in genism?

Which has been created for a specific dataset for performing to LDA.i'm using mac os.

This is my current code:

```
dictionary=corpora.Dictionary(texts)
dictionary.save(Macintosh_HD.Users.srinivasan(bin,'creation.dict'))
```

Comment: Sure. For the record: please consider deleting comments that are no longer required/useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done easily by giving the exact saving Location.

```
  dictionary = corpora.Dictionary(texts)
  dictionary.save('/Users/Srinivasan/bin/creation.dict')
```

to check dictionary:

```
 print(dictionary)
 print(dictionary.token2id)
```